# Safe footnotemarks and automatically call \footnotetext with tcolorbox

Tags: floats, footnotes, automation, tufte

I am trying to use `tcolorbox` with `tufte-book`. The known problem is, that tufte's floating sidenotes are not working with tcolorx theorems. I have the following workaround:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{TcbTheorem}{Theorem}{
    colback=blue!5, colframe=blue!5, coltitle=red,
}{thm}

% sidenotemark
\let\sidenotemark\footnotemark
\NewDocumentCommand\sidenotetext{om}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}%
    {\@footnotetext[#1]{#2}}%
    {\footnotetext{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{TcbTheorem}{Name}{ref}
        Test\sidenotemark

        Another\sidenotemark
    \end{TcbTheorem}
    \sidenotetext{First}
    \sidenotetext{Second}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to automate the calls to `\sidenotetext` at the end of the theorem?

I guess this requires to save everything in a list.

Comment: Apparently tufte uses `\@tufte@sidenote` for both footnotes and sidenotes, if if one doesn't work for one, it won't work for the other.

Comment: My MWE is a workaround for this problem. I just want to make it automated.

Comment: Tufte `\@footnotetext` uses `\marginpar`.  You could probably use the marginnote package.  OTOH I see that tcolobox and tufte both use `\@mpfn` to contain the counter name for footnotes.

Comment: I tried the marginpar package. It has strange effects. Therefore my workaround above.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to replace `\marginpar` with `\marginnote` (marginnote package),
but only inside tcolorbox.  The biggest problem with `\marginnote` is that the notes tends to overlap.

`\TCBsidenote` also uses the global footnote counter instead of `mpfootnote`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{TcbTheorem}{Theorem}{
    colback=blue!5, colframe=blue!5, coltitle=red,
}{thm}

\let\tuftenote=\marginnote
\let\marginnote\relax% make compatible
\usepackage{marginnote}
\let\auxmarginpar=\marginnote
\let\marginnote=\tuftenote% restore original

\makeatletter
\let\@sidenotemark\@footnotemark
\let\@sidenotetext\@footnotetext
%
\long\def\@tufte@sidenote[#1][#2]#3{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@loadnatbib}}{%
    \let\cite\@tufte@infootnote@cite%   use the in-sidenote \cite command
  }{}%
  \gdef\@tufte@citations{}%           clear out any old citations
  \ifthenelse{\NOT\isempty{#2}}{%
    \gsetlength{\@tufte@sidenote@vertical@offset}{#2}%
  }{%
    \gsetlength{\@tufte@sidenote@vertical@offset}{0pt}%
  }%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
    % no specific footnote number provided
    \stepcounter\@mpfn%
    \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
    \@sidenotemark\@sidenotetext[\@tufte@sidenote@vertical@offset]{#3}%
  }{%
    % specific footnote number provided
    \begingroup%
      \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax%
      \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
    \endgroup%
    \@sidenotemark\@sidenotetext[\@tufte@sidenote@vertical@offset]{#3}%
  }%
  \@tufte@print@citations%            print any citations
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@loadnatbib}}{%
    \let\cite\@tufte@normal@cite%       go back to using normal in-text \cite command
  }{}%
  \unskip\ignorespaces%               remove extra white space
  \kern-\multiplefootnotemarker%      remove \kern left behind by sidenote
  \kern\multiplefootnotemarker\relax% add new \kern here to replace the one we yanked
}
\newcommand{\TCBsidenote}{\def\@mpfn{footnote}% setup
  \let\thempfn=\thefootnote
  \let\marginpar=\auxmarginpar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{TcbTheorem}{Name}{ref}
      \TCBsidenote% local setup
        Test\sidenote{First}

        Another\sidenote{Second}
    \end{TcbTheorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. The following does what I want:

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\def\@me@blocknotemarks@keys@add#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname @me@blocknotemarks@keys@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\@me@blocknotemarks@keys@get#1{\csname @me@blocknotemarks@keys@#1\endcsname}

\newcounter{@me@blocknote@size}
\newcounter{@me@blocknote@iter}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bsidenotemark}{}{%
    \addtocounter{@me@blocknote@size}{1}\footnotemark
    \@me@blocknotemarks@keys@add{\the@me@blocknote@size}{\thefootnote}
} 

\NewDocumentCommand{\bsidenotetext}{O{0pt}m}{%
    \addtocounter{@me@blocknote@iter}{1}
    \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\@me@blocknotemarks@keys@get{\the@me@blocknote@iter}}%
    \@footnotetext[#1]{#2}      
}

\gdef\@me@blocknote@lists@pending{\relax} % create empty list
\NewDocumentCommand{\bsidenote}{O{0pt}m}{%
    \bsidenotemark{}%
    % will be executed by \bsidenoteprocess
    \listgadd{\@me@blocknote@lists@pending}{\bsidenotetext[#1]{#2}} 
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bsidenoteprocess}{}{%
    \forlistloop{}{\@me@blocknote@lists@pending}
    \gdef\@me@blocknote@lists@pending{\relax} % claer list
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bmarginnote}{O{0pt}m}{%
    \listgadd{\@me@blocknote@lists@pending}{\marginnote[#1]{#2}} 
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{TcbTheorem}{Theorem}{
    colback=blue!5, colframe=blue, coltitle=blue,
    after={\bsidenoteprocess},
}{thm}


\begin{document}
\begin{TcbTheorem}{}{}
    \begin{itemize} 
        \item A\bsidenote{Aa}
        \item B\bsidenote[3cm]{Bb}
        \item \bmarginnote[5cm]{foo}
    \end{itemize}
\end{TcbTheorem}
\end{document}
```